# Como pegar o id de um usuário dentro da criação de um Validator no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function boot() 
{ 
   //Criação de uma nova validação 

   \Validator::extend('unique_cpf', function ($attribute, $value, 
    $parameters, $validator) { 
          $value = str_replace(['.','-'],'', $value); 
          return ((DB::table('tab_medicos') 
         ->where('med_cpf','=', $value)->where('med_id', '=', 9964) 
         ->count()) == 1); 
   }); 
}
```

No lugar do '9964' eu quero que seja o id, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Podemos pegar desta maneira, onde no qual estamos pegando da url:

```
request()->route('id');
```